# Did a validation to filter active/inactive cellphone number from database

Tags: android, validation, mobile, desktop-application, phone-number

I'm working on online marketing, I often sent SMS to the customer's cellphone number through the EXCEL database. However, there is a lot of cellphone number that is inactive and it's not possible for me to call one by one manually to check which number is still active and inactive.

In order to save on the cost of my SMS blast, I want to do validation of my database to filter the cellphone number that's still active.

So, how can I do mass validation to the cellphone number with more effective and efficient? Also, it's possible to make a desktop/mobile/web apps to did a mass missed call and give a report with the status of the cellphone number (active/inactive)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use numverify api
https://numverify.com/documentation

sample code

```
$access_key = 'YOUR_ACCESS_KEY';

// set email address
$phone_number = '14158586273';

// Initialize CURL:
$ch = curl_init('http://apilayer.net/api/validate?access_key='.$access_key.'&number='.$phone_number.'');  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

// Store the data:
$json = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

// Decode JSON response:
$validationResult = json_decode($json, true);

// Access and use your preferred validation result objects
$validationResult['valid'];
$validationResult['country_code'];
$validationResult['carrier'];
```